# sql script from base

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-scripts

in my project database model is changed periodically, but since database contains test data they have to re-enter each time.
script to insert data quickly becomes relevant. at the moment it is done manually. how this can be done using sql management studio?
I need a script with the data from the tables (to insert ready data to a new table), the script for the database model I have.

for example: i have table [dbo].[Users], table has 3 column [Id],[Login],[Email] and currency contain only one user(Id = 1, Login = 'Anton', Email = 'fake@mail.com')...i create script for my base and resul will be somthink like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Login] decimal(1024)  NOT NULL,
    [Email] nvarchar(1024)  NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO Users([Id],[Login],[Email]) VALUES(1, 'Anton', 'fake@mail.com')
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to use bcp to export the data as flat files, and bcp again to import them when you start with a fresh database? I'm not sure if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a standalone official [tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5498) with which you can create schema and data dumps as sql scripts. Just follow the wizard and make sure you've set the checkbox to export data. As far as I know, it comes included into SQL Management Studio 2008 or later.